# How can I use Lua's string.len() inside a metapost function?

Tags: context, metapost, lua

I am designing pseudo-crosswords for my pupils exercices with the following macro:

```
\startMPinclusions
% could'nt achieve using the word string length as a first parameter
vardef MotMystere (expr taille,speciale,index) =
   numeric avant,apres;
   path case;
   case:= fullsquare scaled 13;
   avant=speciale-1;
   apres=taille-speciale;
   if avant >= 1:
      for j=1 upto avant:
         draw (case rotated 180
            cutafter point 3 of case rotated 180)
            shifted (-13j,-13*index);
      endfor;
   fi;
   label.lft (index,point 3.5 of 
      case shifted (-13*avant,-13*index));
   draw case yshifted (-13*index);
   fill case yshifted (-13*index)
      withcolor \MPcolor{gray-8};
   if apres > 0:
      for j=1 upto apres:
         draw (case cutafter point 3 of case) 
            shifted (13j,-13*index);
      endfor;
   fi;
enddef;
\stopMPinclusions
\starttext
An example with "enigma"

\startMPcode
MotMystere(6,4,1)
\stopMPcode
\stoptext
```

I tried to spare some error-prone counts using `string.len()`. The idea would be to give the word as a first parameter, instead of its manually counted string length, eg `MotMystere("enigma",4,1)`. However I couldn't figure out how should I pass this string parameter to the lua function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in ASCII mode, MetaPost's `length` should suffice. Otherwise, you might need to use `utflen`:

```
\startMPinclusions
vardef MotMystere(expr taille, speciale, index) =
    save avant,apres,case; 
    numeric avant,apres;
    path case;
    case  := fullsquare scaled 13;
    avant := speciale-1;
    %Use parentheses to avoid issues in LMTX
    apres := (length(taille)) - speciale;
   if avant >= 1:
        for j=1 upto avant:
            draw (case rotated 180
            cutafter point 3 of case rotated 180)
            shifted (-13j,-13*index);
      endfor;
   fi;
    label.lft (index,point 3.5 of 
    case shifted (-13*avant,-13*index));
    draw case yshifted (-13*index);
    fill case yshifted (-13*index)
        withcolor \MPcolor{gray-8};
    if apres > 0:
        for j=1 upto apres:
            draw (case cutafter point 3 of case) 
                shifted (13j,-13*index);
        endfor;
    fi;
enddef;
\stopMPinclusions
\starttext
An example with "enigma"

\startMPcode
MotMystere("enigma",4,1)
\stopMPcode
\stoptext
```

As you ask about the way Lua handles your string, Lua (>=5.3) provides an [`utf8`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.5) library with `utf8.len` returning the length of an Unicode strings. Additionally, LuaTeX and LuaMetaTeX provide `string.utflength` and ConTeXt is smart enough to choose either of the functions when available. Although you're able to define your own Unicode functions from Lua and then make them visible to MetaPost, the following are already defined in ConTeXt (`mp-luas.mpiv` or `mp-luas.mpxl`): `utflen`, `utfnum` and `utfsub`. See the example below:

```
\startMPpage
%If any of those doesn't work, just add parentheses until Hans fixes it
string Oracion;
Oracion := "El Perú será grande, el Perú será lo que debe ser, si todos los peruanos nos resolvemos a engrandecerlo.";
draw thetextext(utflen(Oracion),1cm*up);
draw thetextext(utfsub(Oracion,1,19),origin);
draw thetextext(utfnum("Ñ"),1cm*down); %0xD1=209
\stopMPpage
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the hint; I didn't know `length` works also for strings. However I am dealing with UTF-8. I don't have the latest LMTX, so maybe `utflen` works there. However I'd be interested in an alternative additition involving lua's `string.len()`, since a better knowledge of metapost/lua interfacing in macros should be useful in the future.

Comment: @sztruks Metafun's `utflen` is based on Lua's `string.len` (actually `utf.len` for Unicode strings in ConTeXt)!  You can see the relevant definitions within `mp-luas.mpiv` and `mlib-mpf.lua` in case you're interested